# How I can get screen density when I don't have activity-object to get windowManager?

Tags: android

I'm writing a control library, I want to get the screen density of current device, then use it to draw something. How I can get screen density when I don't have activity-object to get windowManager?

```
DisplayMetrics metric = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metric);
int width = metric.widthPixels;
int height = metric.heightPixels;
float density = metric.density;
```

Comment: without context or activity object you can't get width , height

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess your method is in a class. So if you have a `Context` object accessible, use the context's `getResources().getDisplayMetrics()` method!

Contexts are everywhere in android. If you have a view, you can get the context by calling `getContext` on the view. If you have an activity, it's even better because activity *is* a `Context`.

Which means, you need a `Context` object!

Your method must be in a class. So you can add a `Context` field to your class and you can add a parameter to your constructor and let the client code provide a context for you:

```
private Context context;
public YourClassName (Context c) {
    context = c;
}
```

This thing has been implemented in android a lot of times. e.g. `View`'s constructor and `PreferenceManager.getDefaultPreferences`.

Answer (score 0):

You just need a `context`, `application` or `activity`:

```
DisplayMetrics dm = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
```